# openCL создание функций, передача многомерных массивов

Tags: c#, opencl

начал изучать openCL и столкнулся с несколькими проблемами:

- как создать функции в openCL?
- как передавать многомерные массивы в функции __kernel?
- какой тип совместим в C# с типом float2, float3, float4 или их передавать можно только как float?
- Какие редакторы есть удобные по openCl?

П.С. работаю в C# WPF через библиотеку Cloo

Comment: на первый вопрос нашел ответ путем подбора, название функции не должно совпадать с существующими функциями и синтаксис как у С. объявлять наверное нужно так же до использования как и в С. мой пример: float mylength(float x, float y){
return sqrt(x*x+y*y);
}